# REDIS (error) ERR unknown command 'set' on Redis 3.0.4

Tags: redis

I just installed Redis 3.0.4 on Ubuntu Server 11.04.3 LTS

I'm running redis-cli but when I type

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set myKey hello
```

or

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set myKey 'hello'
```

or

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set myKey "hello"
```

it displays

```
(error) ERR unknown command 'set'
```

if I type

```
127.0.0.1:6379> help set
```

it displays

```
SET key value [EX seconds] [PX milliseconds] [NX|XX]
summary: Set the string value of a key
since: 1.0.0
group: string
```

I leave here the info that Redis gave me for more help

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info
# Server
redis_version:3.0.4
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:ca8b1c102698f8cb
redis_mode:sentinel
os:Linux 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.8.4
process_id:1196
run_id:28b1360b9c9c17d2c4645a0b541a080c6c35a263
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:3212
uptime_in_days:0
hz:18
lru_clock:1675551
config_file:/etc/redis.conf
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Your `redis_mode` suggests you're not running what you claim you're running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem

at the config file redis.conf I put a valid path to the directive "dir" under SNAPSHOTTING

```
dir /some/valid/path/
```

also have to change the default value of 128 on /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn to 511

and just restart the service and it worked

Answer (score 3):

You probably ran as redis-sentinal <...redis.conf> but your redis master is not running or unavailable or was never configured. sentinal is a failover mechanism and mostly runs on different node than master.

If you want to run the redis server in standalone mode you can just run this
redis-server < path to redis.conf>. This will let you connect and get going.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the redis.conf file had

```
############################### Disable some dangerous commands ############## 
rename-command CONFIG ""
```

by commenting that line and restarted redis solved it